# Clojure clojure.string/split hit java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Tags: clojure, casting, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop, charsequence

I tried to write a function to process a line of string by calling str\split, the function works fine if i call it directly in LEIN REPL window, but will hit the above call error while trying to run the program from LEIN RUN. 
Any suggestion?

```
(let [num-letters (count (apply str line))
      num-spaces-needed (- column-length num-letters)
      num-words (count  (clojure.string/split line #"\s"))
      num-space-in-group (if (= 1 num-words) num-spaces-needed (/ num-spaces-needed (- num-words 1)))
      group-of-spaces (repeat num-space-in-group " ")
      padding (create-list-spaces num-spaces-needed (dec (count line)))]
  (   clojure.string/join "" (if (empty? padding) (cons line group-of-spaces) 
                (cons (first line) (interleave (rest line) padding)))))
```

Comment: Could you show exactly how you're calling this code, both with `lein repl` and with `lein run`?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you pass `line` as a parameter to your function, although it was omitted from your code snippet.

You should check for differences in the `line` parameter, when calling the function from these two different entry points. First, let's name your function as `tokenize` for convenience. Now, the vanilla `app` template in Leiningen creates a `-main` that looks similar to this, after I add the `tokenize` call:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (tokenize args))
```

The arguments are destructured with the rest operator `&`, which builds a *Seq* of the arguments (`args`). So, when running this with `lein run I want this to work!`, you end up invoking the `tokenize` function with a sequence. `clojure.string/split` cannot be applied to a sequence, and you get a stack trace.

However, when you call your function from `lein repl`, a natural way to do it is with a spell like `(tokenize "Iä! Iä! Cthulhu fhtang!")`. This will work, as your call parameter is now just a string, not a sequence.

In the end, it comes down to how you call your function. A more confident answer would require details on that, as @sam-estep commented.